# Will I really see the angel of death when I die?

Tags: doubts

Basically I’ve been dealing with this doubt I randomly thought of about a year ago. We live in a world where everything is plain/straightforward and can be logically explained. It’s hard for me to grasp the concept that when I die I’ll see the angel of death. I don’t know if this makes sense but hopefully someone can help clear this up Inshallah it’s been eating away at me for a while.

Comment: Please frame your question concretely and not just a "feeling". Also expand on your question what you find illogical about the angel of death and why.

Answer (score -1):

One of the great tragedies of the modern education has been to express physical laws as absolute; shifting the perspective from God-driven to laws-driven which is, an understandable and inevitable consequence to the reactions of the theists to science in the olden days.

But for Muslims, believing that natural laws are absolute and that even God is restricted by them is wrong. Dr.Israr Ahmad even termed it a modern form of shirk, as destructive as idol worshiping. How can God be restricted by laws when He Himself created them?

Another consequence of this thought was the attempt to explain miracles and the unknown using physical laws. Some said angels do not exist, they are just metaphors that represent natural laws. Some said Musa (AS) parting the sea was actually strong winds driving the water up. Essentially a disbelief in the nature of miracles and the unknown.

A miracle or the unknown by definition is something that defies logic and laws of nature. And Allah and his power of creation is above any physical or natural laws.

That said, there may or may not be a theory to explain the presence of angels in the future. No one can say anything about the future with any certainty. Until then, we can only believe with true certainty the word that Allah has given us. He has affirmed that angels exist, and so shall we believe.